# Custom Context Menu option for duplicating selected file not working as expected

Tags: windows-7, command, registry, contextmenu, command-prompt

I am trying to create a custom Context Menu option for duplicating the selected file and appending date and time string to the copied file's name.

Below is the command I have set in registry, in the HKCU > Softwares > Classes > * > Shell > Duplicate This File > Command:

```dos
cmd /s /d /c @echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & set TIME=%TIME: =0% & set DateTimeFn=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_!TIME:~0,2!-!TIME:~3,2!-!TIME:~6,2! & copy /y %1 %1_!DateTimeFn! & pause > nul
```

But somehow the enabledelayedexpansion doesn't work correcty, cause when I try to use this on file `test.js` it duplicates it as `test.js_!DateTimeFn!`.

Also it doesn't work well with spaces in filenames. Can anyone guide and help fix this ?

I would prefer one-liner over creating separate batch script as far as it's possible.

Sample of registry file in which I am trying to run the command with switches and variable expansions:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate This File II]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate This File II\command]
@="cmd /v:on /c @echo off & set TIME=%TIME: =0% & set DateTimeFn=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_!TIME:~0,2!-!TIME:~3,2!-!TIME:~6,2! & copy /y %1 %1_!DateTimeFn! & pause > nul"
```

Comment: Get rid of the setlocal and use CMD /V:ON

Comment: Do I remove the other switches and use the only switches you suggested and remove setlocal ?

Comment: Did you read the help file for what those options do?

Comment: Export the registry setting so I can replicate what you are doing.  Please update your question with that info and also remove your comment with all that code and add it to your question.

Comment: Please check the updated question for registry code..

Comment: I got it to work by doubling the percent symbols in the environmental variables but I can't get the command modifiers to work so that the timestamp can be put inbetween the file name and file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the argument in a FOR command and then you can use the command modifiers to get the file name separated from the extension.

```
cmd /Q /V:ON /E:ON /C "set TIME=%%TIME: =0%% & set DateTimeFn=%%DATE:~10,4%%-%%DATE:~4,2%%-%%DATE:~7,2%%_!TIME:~0,2!-!TIME:~3,2!-!TIME:~6,2! &FOR %%G IN ("%1") do copy "%1" "%%~nG_!DateTimeFn!%%~xG" & pause>nul"
```

Here is the actual registry export.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Time_Stamp_FileName]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Time_Stamp_FileName\command]
@="cmd /Q /V:ON /E:ON /C \"set TIME=%%TIME: =0%% & set DateTimeFn=%%DATE:~10,4%%-%%DATE:~4,2%%-%%DATE:~7,2%%_!TIME:~0,2!-!TIME:~3,2!-!TIME:~6,2! &FOR %%G IN (\"%1\") do copy \"%1\" \"%%~nG_!DateTimeFn!%%~xG\" & pause>nul\""
```